Reading stored response from file in IntelliJ's http-client
I'm using IntelliJ's Http Client plugin to send requests that use OAuth2.
If I create a request for the token, I can then use the response to authenticate subsequent requests:
###
POST http://localhost:{{port}}/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type = client_credentials &
client_id = {{username}} &
client_secret = {{password}} 

> {% client.global.set("token", response.body.access_token); %}

###
POST http://localhost:{{port}}/some-request
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{token}}

{ "a": "body" }

I want to separate getting the token from the actual request. Saving the token works fine:
###
POST http://localhost:{{port}}/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type = client_credentials &
client_id = {{username}} &
client_secret = {{password}} 

>>! oauth-token.json

After running this, oauth-token.json looks like this:
{
  "access_token": "[redacted]",
  "token_type": "bearer"
}

My question is, how do I read oauth-token.json from a different .http file?
I tried various variations on the following:
< ./oauth-token.json
> {% client.global.set("token", response.body.access_token); %}

###
POST http://localhost:{{port}}/some-request
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{token}}

{ "a": "body" }

But I'm getting error:

Error running 'All in some_request'
SyntaxError: C:\path-to\oauth-token.json:10:16 Expected ; but found :

Note that oauth-token.json has four lines and the error is on line ten.

Interesting question! Does setting the token on client.global not work in your use case with multiple .http files? For me it works to access it in the second request in another .http file. Another ugly workaround could be to read the token json from file with the < ./oauth-token.json syntax, post it to an echo endpoint (https://examples.http-client.intellij.net/body-echo) and store the response on client.global (but you probably don't want to do this with an access token :-D ).

@stackoverflowjakob can you expand on the < ./oauth-token.json syntax? If I could post it to echo I could use it for setting the token. Regarding storing the response in client.global this appears to work! I thought it would not be persisted between different runs in different .http files. Thanks for the tip! I would still prefer to be able to read from file for other use-cases.

I am referring to reading the request body from a file, described here: this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/exploring-http-syntax.html#provide-request-body

You can use a JavaScript snippet in your request to load the JSON file, extract the token, and assign it to a variable for further use.
Use client.global.set() to store the token from the JSON file in your .http file:
@import "./oauth-token.json" as oauthTokenJson

> {%
    const tokenData = oauthTokenJson;
    client.global.set("token", tokenData.access_token);
%}

The client.global.set() function stores the access_token globally as "token".
Then use this token in subsequent requests like so:
POST http://localhost:{{port}}/some-request
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{token}}

{ "a": "body" }


Ensure oauth-token.json is in the same directory as the .http file.
Validate that the JSON structure is correct (especially if you're
copying parts of the JSON manually).
Make sure IntelliJ has permission to access the file.

.http file:
### Obtain OAuth2 token and save it to a file
POST http://localhost:{{port}}/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&
client_id={{username}}&
client_secret={{password}}

>> oauth-token.json

### Read the token from the saved file and set it globally
> {%
    // Read the contents of the saved oauth-token.json file
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = './oauth-token.json';
    const tokenData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8'));

    // Set the access_token globally
    client.global.set("token", tokenData.access_token);
%}

### Use the token in an authenticated request
POST http://localhost:{{port}}/some-request
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{token}}

{
  "a": "body"
}


can you give a complete .http file that incorporates these parts? I tried adding the @import in the beginning of my .http file and I'm getting an error between the import and the double-quotes '=' expected got '"'

It appears that IntelliJ doesn't recognize the @import syntax, I see the console shows this as the Request GET http://{%@import"./oauth-token.json"%20as%20oauthTokenclient.global.set("token",%20oauthToken.access_token) %}: 

Edited my answer and added the .http file for you. FYI the IntelliJ HTTP Client provides a way to use JavaScript logic directly within the request body to handle more advanced functionality but does not support @import syntax as it would in typical JS environments.

Thanks @root69 , I apologize for the late reply, I was on vacation...
I try to run the code you posted (without the first request getting the token, just reading from file), and I'm getting the following in the console:
GET http://>{%constfs=require('fs');consttokenData=JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./oauth-token.json', 'utf8'));client.global.set("token", tokenData.access_token);
java.net.MalformedURLException: Illegal character found in host: '>'

It appears that the IntelliJ HTTP Client doesn't support javascript for directly reading files.
Extract the access_token manually from oath-token.json, store it in a .env file and use it on your request like so: Authorization: Bearer {{token}}

Thanks for putting in all the work. The "manually" part of your comment is a deal breaker on my side.

Well, avoiding the manual part is challening, I would create a script to automate token extraction and setting process outside IntelliJ's http client then reference those variables in .httpenv.
